# How to dynamically change the contents of an iframe having different display time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe having the id `demo` and 
I have a list of 5 html files (promo1,promo2,promo3,promo4,promo5) which is to be displayed in the iframes, one after the other, repeatedly. 
Each html page has a different time intervals for which it should be displayed in the frame

Here is my JavaScript code in which the `dict` represents each html and the time for which it should be displayed.

the following code causes multiple invocation of demo function at a time

```
;(function($){

    "use strict";

    var index=1,
      dict={"promo1":70000,"promo2":46500,"promo3":18000,"promo4":93000,"promo5":86000},

    var $firstFrame = $("#demo");

    $(function (){

      function demo(frameId,index){

        frameId.attr("src","static/promo" + index + ".html");
        frameId.load(function(){

          if(index < 5){

            a = setTimeout(demo(frameId , index + 1),dict["promo"+index]);
          }
          else if(index == 5){
            var a = setTimeout(demo(frameId , 1),dict["promo"+index]);
          }
        });
     }

     demo($firstFrame , 1);
     });

}(window.jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your setTimeout action in a function. When you use setTimeout, you want to pass a function to be called later. Otherwise, you are calling demo immediately and passing the return value.

```
setTimeout(function() {demo(frameId , 1),dict["promo"+index];});
```